# find string that begin and end with X or . regular expressions

Tags: regex, sas

I want to detect expressions that contains both [X] and [.]
like :

```
".......X...."
"X..........."
"...........X"
"XXXXXXXX...."
"........XX.."
"........XXXX"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

and not like

```
"............" .
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? Explain specifically what you are trying to match and what is not allowed. Does the last pattern not match because it contains any character besides an [X] or [.]? Why does all `XXXXXX` match, but `........` doesn't?

Comment: Your first example `'....X...'` does NOT begin with X.

Comment: this the results of proc compare, show the difference found in two datasets values by 'X' . it's can be in the beginning, middle or end of and expression. when show just points '.....' it's just a warning and no differences detected between. my aim is to catch where the variables of that values with differences and row key to color that value exactly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know sas syntax, but a regex with lookahead does the job:

```
^(?=.*X)[.X]+$
```

This matching strings that contain only `.` or `X` and at least one `X`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex seems like overkill for the problem of "finding strings that begin and end with X".  Say your variable is named `STR` then you could use code like:

```
if char(str)='X' and char(str,length(str))='X' then ....
```

If you want strings that have at least one X and otherwise only have X or . then something like:

```
if indexc(str,'X') and 0=verify(trim(str),'X.') then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't use lookaheads, this may work for you:

```
^\.*X+\.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect strings that *start* **and** *end* with `.` **or** `X` using `in:`, a prefixed comparison operator.

```
where stringValue in: ('.', 'X') and reverse(trim(stringValue)) in: ('.', 'X')
```